# axios set custom cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, axios

Im trying to set a custom cookie, for axios requests. But it's not working.

Thats my code

```
const axios = require('axios');
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

const client = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true
});

let url = 'https://google.de';

client
    .get(url, {
        headers: {
            Cookie: [
                'cookie1=value;'
            ],
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
        }
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res.headers['set-cookie']); // Im getting "undefined"
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

i tried different ways, but have no luck. maybee any one know how i can set custom cookies in axios? or recommend a better library to do that..

Comment: Why do you expect setting a cookie on the request to trigger a set-cookie header on the response?

Comment: Why are you setting access control headers on the request? They are response headers!

Comment: What environment are you running your JS in? The use of `require` implies Node.js but you might be transpiling it and running it in a browser.

Comment: I only need to set a cookie in axios. its important for my webscript. i know about puppeteer and phantomjs, but i don't like it because cpu and other reasons. its very slow.

Comment: Repeating that you are using axios doesn't answer *any* of the points I raised in my comments.

Comment: how i can do it , i don't understand it know.. sry. Im a newbie in cookies/headers

Comment: about the controls, i don't know.. i copied it from stackoverflow questions.

Comment: @quentin Im using npm

Comment: my environment is nodejs